# Methods for randomly allocating people between active and placebo in clinical trials

Tags: experiment-design, clinical-trials

I'm looking for a way to allocate people to either group A or B.
Data for the study group has 3 main variables:

1. Age        65-90
2. Male  or Female
3. APOE +    or    APOE – (this is a blood test)

I then need to allocate them to either A (active tablet) or B (placebo).

Ideally, I need both groups A and B to be comparative, so fairly even. Total number of participants will be 120. Can anyone suggest a random allocation method for doing this?
Or is it perhaps better to just randomly assign and completely ignore the above variables?

Answer (score 5):

If you have good reasons to think that these three factors influence the outcome, you may want to block them. Otherwise, you could still use blocking (e.g., Imai, King, & Stuart, 2008), but it's probably not that important in that case.
Search for [blocking](/questions/tagged/blocking) on this site, or [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomized_block_design), or ...

Imai, K., King, G., & Stuart, E. A. (2008). Misunderstandings between experimentalists and observationalists about causal inference. *Journal of the Royal Statistical Society, 171*, 481–502. doi: 10.1111/j.1467-985X.2007.00527.x

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all three factors are prognostic (i.e. strongly related to the primary outcome) the most common methods of balancing them within the treatment groups are:

1. Random permuted blocks within strata
2. Minimisation

In both cases you must categorise your age variable - it's usual to create 2 categories based on median age in your patient population unless you have other pre-defined cut-points. Let's assume you categorise into 65-75 and 76-90 years.

The potential problem with using blocks within strata is that you have 8 strata (2 age-groups x 2 sexes x 2 APOE states) and only 120 patients. In the best case assuming you recruit 50% females and 50% APOE+, you would have 15 patients per strata. In reality you're likely to have some strata with fewer patients and others with more. If, for instance, being APOE+ is rare (5%) then the APOE+ strata (65-75/Male/APOE+, 76-90/Male/APOE+, 65-75/Female/APOE+, 76-90/Female/APOE+) are likely to have only 1 or 2 patients each. This would mean you don't have enough patients within these strata to complete any blocks, so the blocking doesn't get a chance to work and balance the treatments. You can choose very small blocks (size 2) to combat this, but it makes the allocation sequence more predictable which is undesirable.

Minimisation [doesn't suffer from this problem](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12505244) with sparse strata, but is complicated to implement. You would need to use some specialist software or an online randomisation service if you choose minimisation.